# How do I represent longblob in drupal db_query?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have the following query and I want to make it a parameterized query.

In the database (mysql), data is type **longblob**. How do I represent that in the query?

```
db_query("UPDATE {tf_buyitframed} SET data = '$pxml', price = $price, thumb_fid = '$jpg' ,date='$date' WHERE bifid = $bifid LIMIT 1");
```

This is the almost finished query:

```
db_query("UPDATE {tf_buyitframed} SET data = '$pxml', price = %f, thumb_fid = '%s', date='%d' WHERE bifid = %d LIMIT 1", $price, $jpg, $date, $bifid);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It should be no different than any other parameter substitution, what errors are you getting when you try passing the variable as a parameter to `db_query` using a `%s` as normal?

Comment: I haven't tried using %s. I wasn't sure if there was a different one for a blog datatype.

Comment: There are only two, `%d` and `%s`...I'd wager using `%s` will work in this case

Comment: @Clive: There are three more, namely `%n` (numeric), `%f` (float) and `%b` (blob).

Comment: @HenrikOpel: Yes you're right I didn't know that, it's been a while since I dipped into Drupal 6 development. Thanks for putting me straight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try the same as for a 'normal' blob, which would be `%b`.

See the source of [db_type_placeholder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_type_placeholder/6) for the Drupal 6 mappings of Schema API field types to placeholders (Schema API would declare a longblob as type 'blob', with size 'big' - see [Data types](http://drupal.org/node/159605)).